# Polymer paper-input attributes in mobile browser

Tags: polymer

How to get to the paper-input attributes in mobile browser?

Next lines work fine on a PC but on a mobile all 3 alerts displays the same value: 'input' - which is not what 'id' and 'c_field' are containing.

```
    <div class="validation">
             <paper-input 
                          type='number' 
                          id='custom_1' 
                          c_field="custom field"
             ></paper-input>
    <div>
    <script>
            document.querySelector('.validation').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
                         alert(e.target.id);
                         alert(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('id').value);
                         alert(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('c_field').value);
            }
   </script>
```

(mobile tests on Chrome v.25.1 and Firefox v.31 on Android v.4.1)

Final goal is to use 'c_field' for some AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code on jsbin on my computer and the alerts didn't work there too, so I changed the event listener to "change" and selected the paper-input element directly:

http://jsbin.com/jakuxozoyawa/2/edit (tested on Chrome Beta on Android)